# Flutter riverpod loading under consumer causing over while using circularprogressindicator

Tags: flutter

[image]I am creating an flutter app and using riverpod futureprovider. Everything works perfectly fine except the loading part of consumer. Since Consumer only rebuild a container with small height. The circular progress indicator overflow the container causing error.
I want data to be shown within the container but on loading I want to use full screen. it it Possible.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '../providers/size_provider.dart';

class SpaceCheck extends StatelessWidget {
  final String diskLabel;
  final Color color;

  SpaceCheck(this.diskLabel, this.color);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Text(
                diskLabel,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
                    ),
                    Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
                      final responseAsyncValue = watch(responseProvider);

                      return responseAsyncValue.map(
                          data: (_) {
                            return Container(
                                child: FractionallySizedBox(
                              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              widthFactor:
                                  _.value['usedSpaced'] / _.value['diskSize'],
                              child: Container(
                                  height: 5,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: this.color,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6))),
                            ));
                          },
                          loading: (_) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          error: (_) {
                            return AlertDialog(
                              elevation: 10,
                              title: Text('Error'),
                              content: Text(_.error.toString()),
                              actions: [
                                TextButton(
                                  child: Text('Ok'),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            );
                          });
                    })
                  ],
                )),
            Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
              final responseAsyncValue = watch(responseProvider);
              return responseAsyncValue.map(
                  data: (_) {
                    return Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Text(
                        (_.value['usedSpaced'] / 1000).toStringAsFixed(2) +
                            " GB used of " +
                            (_.value['diskSize'] / 1000).toStringAsFixed(2) +
                            ' GB',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  loading: (_) {
                    return Text('test');
                  },
                  error: (_) => Text(_.error.toString()));
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}




import 'package:disk_space/disk_space.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class GetDiskInfo {
  Future getSize() async {
    Map diskDetails = new Map();
    // var diskSize = await DiskSpace.getTotalDiskSpace;
    // var freeDisk = await DiskSpace.getFreeDiskSpace;
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 8));
    diskDetails['diskSize'] = await DiskSpace.getTotalDiskSpace;
    diskDetails['freeDisk'] = await DiskSpace.getFreeDiskSpace;
    print(diskDetails['freeDisk'] + diskDetails['diskSize']);
    diskDetails['usedSpaced'] =
        diskDetails['diskSize'] - diskDetails['freeDisk'];
    return diskDetails;
  }
}

final clientProvider = Provider((ref) => GetDiskInfo());

final responseProvider = FutureProvider<dynamic>((ref) async {
  final diskTest = ref.watch(clientProvider);
  return diskTest.getSize();
});
```

Comment: can you include an image of the `lodaingScreen`?

Comment: my data is only inside the card showing free size and used space.